# Processing nested JSON file in pig

Tags: arrays, json, nested, apache-pig

I am trying to read the below nested JSON array input file in pig. The number of telephone number values would be varying between 1 and 3 for each customer.

Now I need to read the first tel nbr as `Tel1`, second as `Tel2` and third as `Tel3`

```
{"Customer_Info":[{"Tel_Nbr":9999900001},{"Tel_Nbr":9878909877},{"Tel_Nbr":01145565675}]},
{"Customer_Info":[{"Tel_Nbr":7867898789},{"Tel_Nbr":9809878980}]},
{"Customer_Info":[{"Tel_Nbr":8909890989},{"Tel_Nbr":04456767687}]}
```

I tried the below but could not meet my objective.Any help is appreciated.

```
arr = load '/jsonarray.json' using JsonLoader('Customer_Info:{(Tel_Nbr:chararray)}');

val = foreach arr generate BagToTuple(Customer_Info).$0 as Tel1,BagToTuple(Customer_Info).$1 as Tel2, BagToTuple(Customer_Info).$2 as Tel3;
```

But getting the below error

```
2016-03-29 22:37:05,048 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1127: Index 1 out of range in schema:Total_Premium_Amt:double
Details at logfile: /home/mapr/pig_1459315772500.log
```